# The following php code returns a http error 500 using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the sample code which I got error, It works well in localhost when try to run the code in remote server is returns errors, Suggest me is there is any other way to achieve the same function in code.

```
<?php
if (!$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password')) {
die('An error occurred while connecting to the MySQL server!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db(sample)) {
die('An error occurred while connecting to the database!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = array(
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS content;',
'CREATE TABLE content SELECT * FROM sample2.content'
);
if (sizeof($sql) > 0) {
foreach ($sql as $query) {
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
die('A MySQL error has occurred!<br><br>' . mysql_error());
}
}
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Edit your Q plz , you want SQl Server or Mysql ?

Comment: (1) Don't tag your question as `sql-server` when you're not using SQL Server , if in doubt hover over the tags to see what they're about (2) Don't use `mysql_*` functions as they were deprecated since version 5.4 and removed in version 7.0 (3) Use error reporting. If this is a production server then you can log the errors rather than show them and then check the logs for more details on what the error is.

Comment: Basic rule: If you get a 500, you FIRST stop should be the webserver's error log to get details ABOUT the 500. Until you have that, there's nothing we can do to help, except for look for obvious/silly things like typos causing syntax errors.

Comment: I am asking that what is the way to do in php version 7. I could not find solution for it Marc B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, do not use any `mysql_*` functions if you are able to as they have been deprecated as of [PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)  and have been entirely removed in [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php).

There isn't anything wrong with your code other than bad practice and `500` is a generic error code. This could be due to a numerous of things such as:

1. PHP not set up correctly.
2. Apache/Nginx/etc not set up correctly.
3. ...

When you have found your specific error you are receiving, then ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mr. Francisco Mateo